# Enable Transfer Acceleration for AWS SDK for macos

Tags: objective-c, macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

**Disclaimer:** I posted [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161436/enable-transfer-acceleration-for-aws-sdk-for-macos) originally on Code Review but as the code does not currently work I was suggested to post at SO instead.

I have converted the official [AWS SDK iOS](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios) (v 2.5.0) framework (focusing on S3) to macOS and everything is working as expected with uploads and downloads. However, I wanted to also enable [Transfer Acceleration for S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/transfer-acceleration.html) using [AWSTransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html). I know that you can enable Transfer Acceleration (TA) using the [AWSTransferUtility](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transferutility.html), but that utility uses pre-signed requests that are valid for only 50 minutes (useful for iOS but not macOS). I would like to be able to transfer files that are large and can take hours even when using Transfer Acceleration.

I have edited the original code from AWS to enable TA for AWSTransferManager, however, I still can not get this to work properly as the final signing of the upload/download request fails. The error message is:

```
Message=The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.}]
```

For the most part, I have edited the files AWSSignature, AWSS3TransferManager, and AWSService (AWSServiceConfiguration). I think that the signing error occurs because I am editing a path, or URL without correctly [code signing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) the change (probably in AWSSignature.m). As I am uncertain as to where my code breaks, I have created a repository with all of the AWS SKD macOS files required to compile the framework including a [unit test](https://github.com/trondkr/aws-sdk-macos-TA/blob/master/SDBucketAccelerationTest.m). If I run the [test](https://github.com/trondkr/aws-sdk-macos-TA/blob/master/SDBucketAccelerationTest.m) initializing the call to AWSServiceConfiguration with:

```
 AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc]initWithRegion:[region aws_regionTypeValue]                                                                            credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider
                                                                  accelerateModeEnabled:@(NO)
                                                                             bucketName:self.testBucketName];
```

Then everything works as expected and the test file uploads and downloads correctly. However, if I try to turn transfer acceleration on (I have already made sure that my bucket has acceleration enabled), then it fails with the code signing error above.

```
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc]initWithRegion:[region aws_regionTypeValue]                                                                            credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider
                                                                  accelerateModeEnabled:@(YES)
                                                                             bucketName:self.testBucketName];
```

In fact it seems like the test script is trying to upload a file much larger than what the testfile (3 Mb) really is. I assume my error is related to the signing of the URL body in some way as the size of the file seems wrong.

I know that finding this error requires a bigger effort than what is usually expected at SO and it is not something many will throw themselves at (but hopefully some) as it involves very complex code and it is time-consuming. However, I do believe that if we could make this work then many can find the framework for AWS SKD for macOS + Transfer Acceleration very useful.

I hope you will take a look at try to identify what may be my problem breaking the code signing.

All code for the framework+test example is available here: https://github.com/trondkr/aws-sdk-macos-TA. To run the unit test you need to provide the secret key and access id to your AWS S3 and the name of a bucket that has transfer acceleration enabled.

Thanks. Cheers, Trond